# best_in_place ":nil" function does not work in AJAX inserted partial

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I have a list of records on my page. I submit a form remotely via AJAX and the new record is appended to the list. All best_in_place features immediately work apart from the :nil option. This doesn't display the default value that I set. This makes it impossible to edit the value unless the user refreshes the page. Then the value is present and the user can click.

Is this a known bug? Can anyone suggest a work around?

**Updated with my code:**

```
<%= best_in_place_if can?(:update, post), post, :post_type, :path => account_post_path(account,post), :type => :select, :collection => Post::POST_TYPES.zip(Post::POST_TYPES), html_attrs: { "class" => "span2" }, :nil => "Click to assign" %>
```

This is inside a partial called _post.html.erb that gets inserted via a create.js.erb file:

```
$("#js_posts").prepend("<%= escape_javascript render 'post', :post => @post, :account => @account %>");
$("#js_add_post_button").button('toggle');
$("#js_add_post").collapse('hide');
$("#js_add_post").html("<%= escape_javascript render 'add_post', :new_post => Post.new, :account => @account %>");
```

Comment: could you show us some code please?

Comment: @hanswurstchen Updated with my code

Comment: Looks like a bug in the gem. See [here](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/search?q=%3Anil&type=Issues).