# best_in_place does not show nil value when no layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm rendering a partial and rendering it without a layout

```
format.html { render :layout => false }
```

All values are displayed correctly, and are editable with best_in_place as expected. However, nil values are showing empty and thus cannot be edited (i.e. no "-" is shown). Trying to specifically use the :nil option doesn't make a difference.

While rendering a layout it shows correctly, however I must not use the layout.
Any suggestions?

Example code:
  Controller

```
def index
....
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => false } 
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
```

View

```
<td class='centered-cell span2'><%= best_in_place @user, :nick_name, :inner_class => 'span1' %></td>
```

Comment: Please paste some code.

Comment: not clear...what ` nil values are showing empty and thus cannot be edited (i.e. no "-" is shown)` ??

Comment: Yes exactly, when the value of the attribute is nil, instead of a '-' that is usally shown, there is an empty-string, and that can't be edited.

Comment: I've found also other people facing same issue, as in this unresolved issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725948/best-in-place-nil-function-does-not-work-in-ajax-inserted-partial

Comment: OK, I believe to found the answer to this - the nil display is done in the JavaScript section, invoked by the call to $('.best_in_place').best_in_place(). Since this code in my page was called only in the 'ready' JS, it was not called when I've loaded a partial date, thus best_in_place() was not invoked. Calling best_in_place after the AJAX call have solved this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was that i used `type: :select` but `collection:` was empty

so i had to do something like this to catch it for empty selectbox

```
<%= best_in_place [:admin, resource], :select_attr, type: :select, collection: SelectModel.all.map{|sm| [sm.id, sm.name]}.presence||[nil, 'nil'] %>
```